# Embed org task list from other subtree

Tags: org-mode, todo

Is there a way to embed/include/reference (I don't know the proper word in emacs-speek :)) to headings so that their contents show in a different place?

The idea is to reduce duplications and bookkeeping while maintaining different "views" into e.g. project tasks, potentially using shared files

### Example

I write a journal entry in `diary.org` about a meeting and come up with `TODO` headings and task lists:

```
* Diary ...
** 2019-07-24 Meeting recap
I learned a lot of cool things. Bob was really nice. Alice nailed all the details. Wow. Such productivity. But we got new stuff to do!
*** TODO Project X
**** TODO Subtask Y
- [ ] Task A
- [ ] Task B
```

I can configure my agenda to see them.

In addition to showing the stuff in my agenda, I want to include the contents in my project list, e.g. `work.org`:

```
* Current client
** Current Milestone
(Here comes not a copy, but a reference of the stuff from above:)
*** TODO Project X
**** TODO Subtask Y
- [ ] Task A
- [ ] Task B
```

I intend this to be *a reference of the heading*, so that changes in any of the two org files are reflected in the other.

(Of course I wouldn't want to leave tasks in the journal. The example is contrived. But what about sharing tasks with others in an org file in e.g. Dropbox, and having changes reflected in my own files?)

---

Is there a method that I fail to find, maybe because I use the wrong search terms? Or would I have to write a sync function myself?

Comment: Have you looked at [links](https://orgmode.org/manual/Hyperlinks.html#Hyperlinks)?

Comment: @NickD Yes, but links require navigation to another place keeping the context in the back of one's head. I imagine being able to embed (parts of) a task list to get an overview in multiple places.

Comment: You can open links in a different window (or frame) and keep the original context accessible. Embedding (parts of) a task list in a different place will inevitably cause problems: two places where the same information is kept, therefore two sources of truth - when they differ (and they will), who is right? There are ways around this, but they are much more complicated than links.

Comment: This makes sense, and is what I feared would be the answer :) Thank you!